# jQuery not loading on website

Tags: javascript, jquery, loading

Please follow this link: click

The problem is that jQuery is blocked by something or is just not loading. For example, when pressing the "click here if this was helpful" button or when typing something in the search bar, nothing happens. I've done some research and something which can block jQuery is "js/universal/custom.js" which is loaded, but either if it still loads or not, jQuery still doesn't work for those elements.

I don't understand why. Waiting  for your answers! :D

Comment: Could you add the code to the post, and tell us what might be causing `js/universal/custom.js` to block jQuery?

Comment: There is no need to add the code... OP is just trying to eat the pizza before it is made. Scripts are out of order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the developer console (F12 on most browsers), you'll see a bunch of errors that say that jQuery is not defined. You need to put the jQuery  tag before any of your other scripts are declared, preferably (really best practice) in the .

jQuery, however, is loading. It is just loading after you're other scripts have been loaded and executed.

You can test this by opening the developer console and typing

```js
$('#but_full28').bind('click', function() {alert('Clicked');})
```

When you click on the "click here if this was helpful" div, it'll give you an alert.

TLDR: Add the jQuery script tag before all of your other script tags in the head and you'll be all good.

Answer (score 3):

Because you load jQuery AFTER the files that need it. Move it to the top of the includes.

Since you have inline JavaScript in the body that references jQuery, you will need to add the script reference into the head.

Also your HTML is invalid, you have divs inside of your head tag.